# $L^1$ Convergence of Random Variables if and only if Uniform Convergence of Expectation

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X$ be in $L^1$. Show that $X_n \rightarrow X$ in $L^1$ if and only if $\mathbb{E} X_n 1_H \rightarrow \mathbb{E} X 1_H$ uniformly in $H$ in $\mathscr{H}$, that is, if and only if $\lim_n \sup_{H\in \mathscr{H}} |\mathbb{E} X_n 1_H - \mathbb{E}X1_H| = 0.$

I have been able to prove the $(\Rightarrow)$ claim assuming $X_n \rightarrow X$ in $L^1$. As for the other direction, I have been able to make very little progress. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Note: This problem is Exercise 4.11 in Chpater 3 of Çinlar's Probability and Stochastics.

Edit: My proof of $(\Rightarrow)$.

Proof: Suppose $X_n \rightarrow X$ in $L^1$, that is, $\mathbb{E}|X_n - X| <\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon >0$. Observe that
\begin{align*}
    \sup_H |\mathbb{E}X_n1_H - \mathbb{E}X1_H|&= \sup_H |\mathbb{E}(X_n1_H - X1_H)|\\
    &\leq \sup_H\mathbb{E}|X_n1_H - X1_H|\\
    &\leq \mathbb{E}|X_n-X|\\
    &< \varepsilon.
\end{align*}
Now, taking the limit, we get
$$\lim_n\sup_H |\mathbb{E}X_n1_H - \mathbb{E}X1_H| = 0.$$

Comment: It might be a good idea if you showed us what you have tried, and maybe even post your proof of the $(\implies)$ direction.

Comment: @C-RAM I added my proof of the other direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\alpha_n:= \sup_H |\mathbb{E}X_n1_H - \mathbb{E}X1_H|$,
so the hypothesis is that $\alpha_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Let  $H_n^+=\{X_n>X\}$ and $H_n^-=\{X_n<X\}$. Then
$$2\alpha_n \ge |\mathbb{E}X_n 1_{H_n^+} - \mathbb{E}X1_{H_n^+}|+|\mathbb{E}X_n 1_{H_n^-} - \mathbb{E}X1_{H_n^-}|=\mathbb{E}|X_n-X|\,.$$
Thus $\mathbb{E}|X_n-X| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Could you explain further? I am unsure how to apply the hypothesis in this way.

Comment: I explained further.